# How do I deliberately effect a parity error?

Tags: memory, memory-error

Is there a way to directly change the whole byte in memory to effect a parity error?
As far as I know see, manipulating values in RAM or other directly excludes the parity bit, with that being automatic – is it possible without physical intervention?

Answer (score 0):

At the hardware level?   Probably not (assumption based on the existence of the error injection framework I mention below).

You can however simulate the error paths in software with some operating systems.  Linux in particular includes an error injection framework (I believe it's called HWPoison) that will let you directly trigger the in-kernel error paths that get executed when a correctable or uncorrectable error occurs (this is actually part of how those code paths get tested).